# Homotopy between unitary element and identity elements, Operator Theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, operator-theory, operator-algebras, exact-sequence

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the Toeplitz algebra. I.e. the $C^*$ algebra generated by the shift operator $S\in B(l^2(\Bbb N))$.

In [page 6, line 8 of a proof](https://perimeterinstitute.ca/personal/tfritz/2010/bott_periodicity.pdf) we have a unitary element $u \in \mathcal{T} \otimes \mathcal{T}$, and it is claimed that $u$ is homotopic to the identity by a path of unitaries.

The claim seems to be quite general. Is there any reference/ similar result, which I could read to understand more about this?

Answer (score 0):

The unitaries you consider there are self-adjoint. In that particular case, you can write down an easy formula for the path. Let $u$ be a self-adjoint unitary in a C*-algebra. Define $h := (1-u)/2$. Then $e^{\pi i h} = u$ and the path $t \mapsto e^{\pi i th}$ connects $1$ to $u$.

Comment: You commented on an earlier answer, now deleted, and  I think at least part of that comment is worth recording for the benefit of readers who can't see deleted answers: A similar idea works whenever $u$ has a gap in its spectrum (on the unit circle). Namely, drag all the eigenvalues toward $1$ by moving them along the circle away from the gap.(What I don't immediately see: Is a one-point gap enough, or do you need a whole arc?)

Comment: One point missing is enough since the spectrum is closed. Hence there exists a branch of logarithm which is continuous on the spectrum of the unitary.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that "one point missing" implies "a whole arc". (I hope I'm awake now.)