# Homotopy between Unitary with gap in spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, homotopy-theory, spectral-theory

In the comments of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186399/homotopy-between-unitary-element-and-identity-elements-operator-theory) it is mentioned that when a unitary operator has a gap in the spectrum one can show it is homotopic by 'dragging the eigenvalues to $1$ along the unit circle, away from the gap'. How can this be done explicitly? I expect that there will be constructed some continuous function with a branch trough the gap, but how do we get such a transformation, and how does one prove that it's images are unitary operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note that in infinite dimension the spectrum is more than just eigenvalues (and it may have no eigenvalues at all).*

There are a couple things here. If you are talking about homotopy over the full unitary group in $B(H)$, then what you do is you define a branch of the logarithm, and then you use Borel functional calculus to show that $U=e^{iS}$ for some selfadjoint $S$. And then $U(t)=e^{i(1-t)S}$ is a homotopy.

In the question you mention the context is different, though, as the homotopy is considered inside a C$^*$-algebra. That means that Borel functional calculus is not available, and here is where the gap in the spectrum becomes relevant. The gap allows you to construct a *continuous* branch of the logarithm. Then you can find $S=-i\log(U)$, selfadjoint, and an element of the C$^*$-algebra. So again you can construct a homotopy $U(t)=e^{i(1-t)S}$.

Comment: So in the first case, a proof would be of the form:

We define a branch of the logarithm from $\sigma(U)$ to the real line, which is a Borel function and invertible. Then this inverse is given by $f : x \mapsto \exp(i x)$ and is a Borel function as well. This means that there is some self adjoint $S$ such that $f(S) = U$, and then [the homotopy part is quite trivial].

Is this correct? I feel like I've cut some corners I wasn't supposed to.

Comment: Does the Borel functional calculus hold for unitaries? I thought it only held for self adjoint operators?

Comment: Unitaries are normal. Both the continuous and the Borel functional calculus work for normal.